# H1 Font Weight displays different on WordPress Staging Site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

There is something that I am not seeing that I could use some help on.

The CSS for the H1 tag on this site: [www.californiacounselgroup.com](http://www.californiacounselgroup.com) is what I'm trying to put on the staging site.  If you look at "Fixed-Fee Legal Service" on the live site, the text is thin (300 weight).

If you look at the same text on the staging site, it is different.  http://calcou.01hearts.com/ .

I've cleared cache, tried two browsers and inspected element.  I've checked that the "Lato" Google Font is loaded into the theme options the same.

What's am I not seeing here?  Any help would be appreciated.
Teresa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the headers being sent to Google fonts It doesn't appear that you are actually pulling the font weight of 300. I'm only seeing 400, 700 in both regular and italic.

This is how the header parameters are being pulled:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/1YwB1sO8YE1Lyjf12WNiUA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/H2DMvhDLycM56KNuAtbJYA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Italic'), local('Lato-Italic'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/PLygLKRVCQnA5fhu3qk5fQ.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold Italic'), local('Lato-BoldItalic'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/HkF_qI1x_noxlxhrhMQYEFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Try making sure you're actually pulling font weight 300 from Google.

Comment: Thank you kwh71787.  I will try that.

Comment: If it worked please ensure to mark @kwh71787's as the correct one

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to do that inside of this user interface.  I'll figure it out.  Thanks.